# Non-periodic orbit in Newton-Raphson example

Tags: dynamical-systems, newton-raphson

Let $f(z)=\frac{z^2-1}{2z}$. I want to find a point $\xi\in\mathbb{R}$ such that the $f$-orbit of $\xi$ is non-periodic and$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac1n \#\{t\leq n \,:\,f^t(\xi)<0   \}=\frac13.
$$
I just don't know how to approach such problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Yeesh!  For most choices of $\xi$ where there's a nonperiodic orbit the probability will be $1/2$!  You will need some number with peculiar properties to get this to work.

Comment: Which properties? I'm rather new to dynamical systems.